# How to make sure that a subsequent Babel plugin runs after all the processes have been completed?

Tags: javascript, next.js, babeljs, babel-plugin, swc-compiler

I have made my custom babel plugin that transform my code into code that is again transformed by another babel plugin from a totally different library. But my plugin is not able to transform the code completely before that the other plugins starts running.

How to make sure that my babel plugin is done transforming the code before the next babel plugin runs?